# Error 422 (Unprocessable Entity) while making Ajax call on Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my code:

```
class EventController < ApplicationController

  def update
    render :json => { :status => :ok, :message => 'Good Morning'}
  end
end
```

and this is my route entry:

```
post 'event/update', controller:'event', action: :update
```

**Error Message**

```
   <header>
  <h1>
    ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
      in EventController#update
  </h1>
</header>

<div id="container">
  <h2>ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken</h2>



Rails.root: /Clients/M/Application/HITS

Framework Trace
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:176:in `handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:202:in `handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:197:in `verify_authenticity_token'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/JD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/JD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/JD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'

Full Trace
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:176:in `handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:202:in `handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:197:in `verify_authenticity_token'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/JD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/JD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/JD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'



Request parameters
{"name"=>"John",
 "time"=>"2pm"}

Session dump
_csrf_token: "a4y1SDHaXHRkiyIW8AncOYcPgRiO5syFXihKc5qqZlg="
session_id: "0d860d9a22ba027b92fcfa2ec5055965"

Env dump
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.1"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "*/*"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip,deflate"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-US,en;q=0.8,ur;q=0.6"
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: "no-cache"
HTTP_PRAGMA: "no-cache"
REMOTE_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"
REMOTE_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_NAME: "0.0.0.0"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"

Response headers
None

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I sorted it out by adding `protect_from_forgery` which does what `authenticity_token` in form does.

```
class EventController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery
  def list
  end

  def details

    end

  def update
    render :json => { :status => :ok, :message => 'Good Morning'}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to **cross-site request forgery protection** . Rails inserts an `authenticity_token` input inside your form to protect you against it. Run your application and then using Dev Tools (ex Chrome Dev Tools) inspect the page and verify that your form has the following input: (Note that the value attribute will be different)

```
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="f755bb0ed134b76c432144748a6d4b7a7ddf2b71" />
```

Also make sure you are using POST method to send the form